# Macbook keyboard and trackpad behaving strangely - vowels don't work?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, trackpad

The keyboard and trackpad of my early 2015 Macbook Retina started behaving strangely. Keyboard is replaced two years ago and should work fine. This all seems like a software problem.

**Trackpad**

- Trackpad left-click (single finger) acts like right-click
- Trackpad right-click (double finger) acts like right-click
- Attached mouse does the same
- Opening the Settings menu, I can check and uncheck boxes like a normal left click

**Keyboard**

- Yesterday many keys on the keyboard didn't do anything, some worked
- This morning I could login (working keyboard) and typing worked normally
- Just rebooted - not able to login. All vowels don't work (<kbd>a</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>u</kbd>), most consonants work.
- At the login screen (cannot see what I'm typing):

  - <kbd>h</kbd> acts like backspace,
  - keys <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> don't work.

macOS version 12.6.9 (latest updates installed). I have no new software installed lately.

**What can cause this and how can I fix it?**

Comment: It sounds more like hardware to me, try an external keyboard to see if that works ok.

Comment: Start by booting in [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/start-up-your-mac-in-safe-mode-mh21245/mac).  Let's see if the issue persists.